# Find and replace function in Alteryx -How it can be done in Azure Data Flow

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-data-factory

I have a "Find and replace " tool in Alteryx which finds the Col value of csv file1 and replaces it with the look up csv file2 which has 2 columns like
Word and  ReplacementWord.

Example :
Address is a col in Csv file1 which has value like St.Xyz,NY,100067

And Csv file 2 has
Word    ReplacementWord
NY        NewYork
ZBW        Zimbawe  etc....

Now the final Output should be
Address
St.Xyz,NewYork,100067

Please help guys .

Hey here's the problem .I have a "Find and replace " tool in Alteryx which finds the Col value of csv file1 and replaces it with the look up csv file2 which has 2 columns like

Word and  ReplacementWord.

Example :

Address is a col in Csv file1 which has value like St.Xyz,NY,100067

And Csv file 2 has

Word    ReplacementWord

NY        NewYork

ZBW        Zimbawe  etc....

Now the final Output should be

Address

St.Xyz,NewYork,100067

Please help guys .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your scenario in my environment to achieve the desired output I Followed below steps:

- In dataflow activity I took 2 Sources
  **Source 1 is the file which contain the actual address.**
  [image]
  **Source 2 is the file which contain the country codes with names.**
  [image]
- After that I took `lookup` to merge files based on the country code. In lookup condition I provided `split(Address,',')[2]` to split the address string with comma and get the 2nd value from it Which will be the country code based on this : Xyz,**NY**,100067 and column_1 of 2nd source.
  [image]
  Lookup data preview:
  [image]
- Now took `Derived Column` and gave column name as Address with the expression `replace(Address, split(Address,',')[2], Column_2)`  It will replace the What we split in lookup from Address string to value of Column_2
  [image]
  Derived column preview:
  [image]
- then took select and deleted the unwanted columns
  [image]
  Select Preview:
  [image]
- now providing this to sink dataset
  [image]

**Output**

[image]

Comment: I was asking this because ,it was possible in Alteryx tool.So i was finding the best option in ADF.